# What counts as a successful ad view in a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, advertisements

There is one thing about mobile ads that I can't completely understand.
Let's say I put ads in my free mobile game. **What counts as a successful ad view?** When it is just displayed on a user's screen or the user has to open the ad in order for it to count as viewed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The standard as of April 6, 2016 put forth by the Media Rating Council (MRC), Interactive Advertising Bureau (IAB), and Mobile Marketing Association (MMA) in their updated [Mobile Web Measurement Guidelines and Mobile In-Application Measurement Guidelines](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/iab-measurement-guidelines/) call for "reasonable assurance that the ad was rendered on the device in order to count it as a valid ad impression." ([as reported by MarketWatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/medialets-is-first-to-adopt-rigorous-methodology-for-counting-mobile-ads-as-recommended-by-the-mrc-2016-05-03)).

That being said, guidelines may be adopted to varying degrees by providers. Generally the fine print of legal agreements, EULA, etc dictate what will & will not count toward monetization, unless trumped by law. When in doubt, read your contract &/or hire a lawyer for legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can monitise adverts. Different add providers will use different conditions or a mix.

The most common is click through, i.e if the user clicks through the game developer would get a small amount.

Video ads on the other hand are an example of where they would pay just for users to view the ad.